# Show $\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\tan40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+\tan40^\circ\sin50^\circ} =\tan10^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

The question arose in finding $\alpha$ in this diagram:

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [mei.org.uk](https://mei.org.uk/images/miotm/apr-21-pic.png))</sub>

With a bit of work with the sine rule it can be shown that:

$$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(20^\circ)\sin(30^\circ)\tan(40^\circ)}{\sin(20^\circ)\sin(30^\circ)+\tan(40^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)}$$

... and this can be evaluated on a calculator to find $\alpha = 10^\circ$. But I'm not satisfied in using a calculator.

> I want to know if there's a neat way of manipulating the expression on the RHS so that it simplifies out to $\tan(10^\circ)$.

I've had a good go at it - using double/triple/quadruple angle formulae to re-write everything in terms of $\sin(10^\circ)$, $\cos(10^\circ)$ and $\tan(10^\circ)$ and trying to simplify - but just seem to make things more complicated.

Can you find a nice way of doing it?

Comment: Call the vertices $A,B,C$ starting from the top counterclockwise. Reflect each cevian with respect to the angle bisector of the vertex. The reflections will also be concurrent. Call $D$ the point of intersection and $E$ the intersection of $BD$ and the perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. Then $D$ is in two bisectors of the triangle $AEC$. Therefore, it is also in the third bisector. Therefore, the angle $CAD$ is $10$. Thus the angle $\alpha$ is also $10$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Divide the numerator and denominator by $\sin20\sin30= \frac12\sin20$

\begin{align}
&\frac{\sin20\sin30\tan40}{\sin20\sin30+\tan40\sin50}\\
=& \frac{\sin40}{\cos40+4\sin50\cos20}
= \frac{\sin40}{(\cos40+1)+2\cos20}
=\frac{\sin20}{\cos20+1}= \tan10\\
\end{align}
where the identities $\sin2t=2\sin t\cos t$, $\cos2t+1=2\cos^2t$ are used twice each.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: A simpler method. Thanks to [@Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue), for their comment.

$\begin{align}\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\tan40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+\tan40^\circ\sin50^\circ} &= \frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\tan40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+\cot50^\circ\sin50^\circ} \\
&=\tan40^\circ\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+\cos50^\circ} \\
&=\tan40^\circ\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+\cos(20^\circ+30^\circ) } \\
&=\tan40^\circ\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+(\cos20^\circ\cos30^\circ-\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ) } \\
&=\tan40^\circ\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ}{\cos20^\circ\cos30^\circ} = \tan20^\circ\tan30^\circ\tan40^\circ\\
& = \tan10^\circ\end{align}$

---

Now for $\tan20^\circ\tan30^\circ\tan40^\circ = \tan10^\circ$:

Using, $\tan \alpha\tan(60^\circ-\alpha)\tan(60^\circ+\alpha) = \tan(3\alpha)$

Taking
$\begin{align}&\alpha = 10^\circ 
\\& \tan10^\circ\tan50^\circ\tan70^\circ = \tan30^\circ 
\\\Rightarrow& \tan10^\circ\dfrac{1}{\tan40^\circ\tan20^\circ} = \tan30^\circ
\\\Rightarrow&\tan20^\circ\tan30^\circ\tan40^\circ = \tan10^\circ\end{align}$

---

Earlier method:

$\small{\begin{align}\tan\alpha &= \frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\cos40^\circ+\sin40^\circ\sin50^\circ} \\\\
&= \frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin50^\circ+\sin40^\circ\sin50^\circ}\\\\
&= \frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin40^\circ}{\sin50^\circ(\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ+\sin90^\circ\sin40^\circ)} & (\sin90^\circ = 1)\\\\
&= \frac{2\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin40^\circ}{\sin50^\circ((\cos10^\circ-\cos50^\circ)+(\cos50^\circ-\cos130^\circ))}&(\small{2\sin x\sin y = \cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)})\\\\
&=\frac{2\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin40^\circ} {\sin50^\circ(2\sin60^\circ\sin70^\circ)}&(\cos x-\cos y =2\sin\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2 ) \\\\
&=\frac{\sin20^\circ\sin30^\circ\sin40^\circ}{\cos20^\circ\cos30^\circ\cos40^\circ} =\tan20^\circ\tan30^\circ\tan40^\circ \\\\
&= \tan10^\circ\end{align}}$

Comment: You can get to $\tan20\tan30\tan40$ a bit more simply by manipulating the denominator thusly:
$$\begin{align}
\sin20\sin30+\color{red}{\cot50}\sin50 &\to\sin20\sin30+\cos50 \\
&\to\sin20\sin30+\cos(20+30) \\
&\to\sin20\sin30+(\cos20\cos30-\sin20\sin30) \\
&\to\cos20\cos30
\end{align}$$ 
Then, $\dfrac{\sin20\sin30\tan40}{\cos20\cos30}=\tan20\tan30\tan40$, as desired.

Comment: @Blue Yeah it's much simple. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, simpler. Though I enjoyed the invention of $\sin90$ in the first method. Also, I'd not come across that formula for $\tan(3x)$, it's nice. Thanks both!

Comment: @Malkin You're welcome

Comment: I liked your answer for its inventiveness, but happy to change the accepted answer to Quanto's for its concision! I appreciate your selflessness for the sake of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, consider the equation
$$\frac{\sin (2 x) \sin (3 x) \tan (4 x)}{\sin (2 x) \sin (3 x)+\sin (5 x) \tan (4
   x)}=\tan(x)$$
Let $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$ and this write
$$\frac{4 (t-1) (t+1) \left(t^2-3\right) t}{\left(3 t^2-1\right) \left(t^4-10
   t^2+13\right)}+t=0$$ Discarding the trivial $t=0$, this reduces to
$$\frac{3 t^6-27 t^4+33 t^2-1}{\left(3 t^2-1\right) \left(t^4-10 t^2+13\right)}=0$$

The numerator is a cubic in $t^2$ with three real roots since $\Delta=331776$. Using the trigonometric method (!!), they are
$$t^2_k=3+\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{18}-\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}\right) \qquad \text{for} \qquad k=0,1,2$$ They are all positive and the smallest (corresponding to $k=2$) is
$$t^2_2=3-\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)\implies
x=\tan^{-1}\Bigg[\sqrt{3-\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right) } \Bigg]$$

At this point, I am totally stuck but numerically this is $\frac \pi {18}$